# OWASP ZAP report is giving security risk in 2 firefox apis (https://location.services.mozilla.com and https://ftp.mozilla.org)

Tags: security, firefox, http-headers, owasp

I am running ZAP scan on my web application and in that i am getting couple of vulnerabilities related to mozilla's internal apis. I am not calling it from my apis

1. Cross-Domain Misconfiguration

> https://location.services.mozilla.com/v1/country?key=7e40f68c-7938-4c5d-9f95-e61647c213eb
> Evidence: Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *
> https://ftp.mozilla.org/pub/jetpack/tinderbox-builds/
> Evidence: Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *

2. X-Frame-Options Header Not Set

> https://ftp.mozilla.org/pub/system-addons/tls13-version-fallback-rollout-bug1462099/

These two apis response header doesn't have some attributes such as X-Frame-Options and the first error is coming because the response header Access-Control-Allow-Origin is not restrictive.

Kindly suggest how to resolve this or please let me know if this is a false positive case.

Thanks
Chandan

Answer (score 2):

These are endpoints that are called by your browser, not you application. These endpoints do not belong to you, so there is nothing you can do about them. I'd ignore these findings.

Comment: It's important for JavaScript CDN endpoints of common libraries to allow browser origins from any domain, since the libraries could be used by sites on any domain. So even if you could change this setting to be more restrictive, you wouldn't want to, as it would break tons of sites without adding any real security.

This is just another example of website security scanners being misguided (at least if the results are not interpreted by a competent developer or security expert.)